# install packages in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, reshape2

Does anyone know why I cannot instal this:

```
> install.packages("reshape2")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'reshape2' is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2
```

Comment: yep. there's an issue with it right now (i just had the same problem). Use a different repository for the time being.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr for the quick answer! From the warning I expected a workaround. However, I am not sure how to do this. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

run

```
setRepositories()
```

and then, write leaving empty spaces between digits

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

This will include bioclite repositories into RStudio in a temporal fashion